# roku sending request, but nginx not responding or logging

Tags: nginx, roku

I am trying to display a series of short mp4's on my Roku. The idea is to serve them from nginx running on a local host. The Roku hangs on "retrieving" the video. I have used wireshark to witness the requests coming from the roku, and they continuously repeat. Though nginx does not respond, nor does it log the request in access.log or error.log.
I feel that the roku scripts are sufficiently coded as I can confirm that the playlist is received by the video node, the screen is focused, and the request for the video is being made through port 80. I can request the url through a browser and the mp4 plays in the browser if made with http: or in a player if made with rtmp:.

This is the simple nginx configuration in conf.d;

```
server {    
    listen 80 default_server;

    location / {           # the '/' matches all requests
        root /myNginx/sites;   # the request URI would be appended to the root
        index 01_default_test.html; # the index directive provides a default file or list of files to look for
    }

    location /videos/ { # for testing use 'http://10.0.0.13/videos/sample.mp4'
        mp4;    # activates the http_mp4 module for streaming the video
        root /VODs;     # allows adding 'videos' to the uri and the file name 
    }
}
```

}

I appended this to the nginx.conf file;

```
rtmp {
server {
    listen 1935;
    chunk_size 4000;

    # Video on demand
    application VOD {       #  rtmp://10.0.0.13/VOD/sample03.mp4
        play /VOD/videos/;
    }
}
```

Not sure where to go from here. Does anyone know why nginx seems to be ignoring the requests? I am using Ubuntu, and the firewall is currently inactive.

Comment: can you simply connect to the server using a browser?  what happens ?

Comment: hi slim, turns out, everything works just fine through browsers.

Comment: bummer.  could it be a **header issue**